# Querying a remote datasource with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Im trying to implement an asp.net textbox using the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote.

The source property of the widget expects a string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. I have an aspx page that will return the following:

Code Behind:

```
private void GetWidgets(string name)
{
    var jscriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var widgets = jscriptSerializer.Serialize(GetMatchingWidgets(name));
    var script = "Widgets = {\"Widget\": " + widgets + "};";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "JSON", script, true);
}
```

Questions:

1. The documentation says the `The request parameter "term" gets added to that URL.` -- I should therefore be able to get the "term" as a query string parameter correct?
2. Do I have to set the JSON to a variable on the client or does the widget take care of the binding without having to do anything else?

Am I missing anything else?

I would give this a try and just *"figure it out"* but I don't have a whole lot of time to spend on this solution.

Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `term` is the name of the QueryString parameter. All you need to do is return json data in the expected format. For example, here is the class I use...

```
/// <summary>
/// JQuery UI Autocomplete plugin expects an object with "value" and/or "label" property.
/// </summary>
public class AutoCompleteData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// custom property
    /// </summary>
    public string id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// value is shown in text box after selection
    /// </summary>
    public string value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// label is shown in drop down list
    /// </summary>
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

for example...

```
string term = Request.QueryString["term"];

AutoCompleteData[] d = GetMatchingWidgets(term)
    .Select(x => new AutoCompleteData {
        label = x.widgetLabel,
        value = x.widgetValue
    }).ToArray();

return jscriptSerializer.Serialize(d);
```

Comment: So in my example the object `script` would be an array of `AutoCompleteData`?

Comment: yes, it'd be a json encoded array of AutoCompleteData...but, looking at your sample, are you trying to initialize the client with all the data and let it search on the client? I've always done it by dynamically performing the search based on the term parameter.

Comment: fyi, if doing the search on client then you can init the plugin with the source option http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#option-soure I generally use that class when the label and value differ but if they're the same then I think you can just pass an array of strings too.

Comment: I'm doing it that way cause that was the only way I knew how; that's the reason for my question =) My label and value will differ due to requirements so I would be interested in seeing how you do it. Can you edit with a small example?

Comment: oh, then all you need to do is provide a url for the source option. That url would handle the term search and return the json encoded array of AutoCompleteData. Which part do you need an example for?

Comment: Returning the json encoded array of AutoCompleteData with differing label and value.